# How do I target a specific viewController in a custom navigationController code?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have this custom navigationController animation I want to implement, but I want the code to be implement only when a specific viewController is on the stack.. Here is the code:

```
class ARNImageTransitionNavigationController: UINavigationController, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    weak var interactiveAnimator : ARNTransitionAnimator?
    var currentOperation : UINavigationControllerOperation = .None

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.enabled = false
        self.delegate = self
    }

    func navigationController(navigationController: UINavigationController,
        animationControllerForOperation operation: UINavigationControllerOperation,
        fromViewController fromVC: UIViewController,
        toViewController toVC: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning?
    {
        self.currentOperation = operation

        if let _interactiveAnimator = self.interactiveAnimator {
            return _interactiveAnimator
        }

        if operation == .Push {
            return ARNImageZoomTransition.createAnimator(.Push, fromVC: fromVC, toVC: toVC)
        } else if operation == .Pop {
            return ARNImageZoomTransition.createAnimator(.Pop, fromVC: fromVC, toVC: toVC)
        }

        return nil
    }

    func navigationController(navigationController: UINavigationController, interactionControllerForAnimationController animationController: UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning) -> UIViewControllerInteractiveTransitioning? {
        if let _interactiveAnimator = self.interactiveAnimator {
            if  self.currentOperation == .Pop {
                return _interactiveAnimator
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Now what do I add to this code to make sure it implements all its methods but only when a specific viewController is on the stack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have given individual swift classes to the view controllers in question then you can check for their file class name. Say you want this animation when pushing e.g. `ProfilePageViewController`to nav stack, then use `if operation == .Push && toVC.isKindOfClass(ProfilePageViewController)` . I added the remaining code in the code sample you provided.

```
func navigationController(navigationController: UINavigationController,
    animationControllerForOperation operation: UINavigationControllerOperation,
    fromViewController fromVC: UIViewController,
    toViewController toVC: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning?
{
    self.currentOperation = operation

    if let _interactiveAnimator = self.interactiveAnimator {
        return _interactiveAnimator
    }

    if operation == .Push && toVC.isKindOfClass(swiftNameofVCClassFile) {
        return ARNImageZoomTransition.createAnimator(.Push, fromVC: fromVC, toVC: toVC)
    } else if operation == .Pop && fromVC.isKindOfClass(swiftNameofVCClassFile) {
        return ARNImageZoomTransition.createAnimator(.Pop, fromVC: fromVC, toVC: toVC)
    }

    return nil
}
```

Comment: but i do have one more inquiry, would you mind hitting [this chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90086/navigation-transition) very briefly?

Answer (score 0):

This a code we use to get a specific ViewController from the NavigationController stack:

```
class HGViewStack{
    static func findControllerForType<T>() -> T? {
         let navController: UINavigationController = HGApp.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController as! UINavigationController
         let controller: [T] = navController.viewControllers.filter({ $0 is T }).map({$0 as! T})
         return controller.first
    }
}
```

You can use it in all your function defined here like that:

```
if let viewController: MyViewController = HGViewStask.findControllerForType() {
    // Your code
}
```

Unfortunately, those functions will affect all your controllers, they just will have no effect, if that what you want.

Comment: so it will on have an effect on the viewController I want it to correct? because thats what I want

Comment: I think so, you check weather or not the viewController is on the stack and get the reference.

Comment: so that helped the navigationController to pick my specific viewController when it was in the stack and perform the given methods

Comment: but how about when the navigationController is pushing that view out the stack, meaning going back? how do i just stop the method at that specific viewController and not effect any of the previous controllers?

Comment: can you look into this chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90086/navigation-transition

Comment: If the viewController is out of the stack, it won't validate the if statement. From there, your function will have no effect.